# Want to store small video files in database

Tags: android, mysql, video

I'm trying to implement a video chat application that use lively recorded videos of maximum 1 MB of size and 60 sec duration. The video is saved in memory card of my android device. How could I insert the data that is in the sd card to db and retrieve it by another user. Whenever the second party receives file, I want to delete it from the db too..

(All tutorials shown how can we insert video file from our PC not from mobile)

Please help me.. I'm tired of putting many options.

Comment: Why do you have to store the video there if you're already storing it on the SDCard? Why not just store the file location as a string in there?

Comment: cant u store it as a BLOB ?

Comment: Are you really running MySQL on your Android device?

Comment: please help me with a code